# How to add drivers to windows

Tags: windows

So the problem. 
    I have two pc A and B. 
    I took A pc HDD and made a full clone to pcs B HDD. 
    B - has different hardware and now when i try to boot it does not find my HDD. When i insert windows 7 installation cd, and choose repair i can upload drivers and my OS is now visible but just for that moment. 
    After reboot i can't see. I think it is becouse at repair window it only load driver to RAM and after reboot it removes it. 
     My question. Is there any tool that i can put drivers to my OS that it could recognize my HDD and boot.
    I can't boot to safe mode. Changing raid+ahci to ide in bios does not help.

Comment: Is it ide or sata?.

Comment: sata. I am using Intel 520 series 240 GB SSD. My old ssd is the same just new hardware. I know what driver it need, but i don't know how to insert it to OS.

Comment: I'm amazed this worked at all unless A and B use the same chipset?

Comment: The problem might be with your bios. Try upgrading it.

Comment: gladiator2345 it can't be the bios issue. Because if i make a full and clean install and before installation i load Intel(R) C600 Series Chipset SATA RAID Controller the instalation will be succesfully. I need to install that driver but i don't know yet how to do it..

Comment: In BIOS, change sata mode from ahci to ide.